# OMNET++ installation takes long time after executing the make command

Tags: omnet++

Every time when I want to use the OMNET++ simulator, I run the mingwenve,  then./configure, then when I execute the 'make' command,  it takes about 40 minutes to finish.  Is there a way to reduce this time.  Because every time I  execute the 'make' command I have to wait about 40 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The OMNeT++ simulator should be configured and built (i.e. running make) only ONCE. After that you should build ONLY your own models not the whole OMNeT++ simulator.

As for the time. MinGW's API emulation and the Windows filesystem IO speed makes building OMNeT++ (and your own models) pretty slow (compared to other alaternatives)

Having an SSD instead of HDD helps a lot. Using Linux instead of Windows helps also a lot. If you are stuck on Windows (10), you can try running/developing on the Windows subsystem for Linux. Here is a bit help, how te set it up: https://docs.omnetpp.org/articles/wsl2/